# How to add leaflet geoJSON markers dynamically near user position

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation, leaflet, geojson

I'm looking for a way to add some markers near the position of an user. At the moment I'm able to generate markers and put them on a leaflet map randomly by creating some latitude and longitude points but this is not exactly what I want need, I want that after the user geolocation, some markers will be added on the map near the user position at a variable distance between 2,5km and 5km, if possible in a radius range. I'm trying to make something like the pokemon go logic that will add markers on the map by considering the user position.

I'm using this code at the moment in my vue app to create the markers

```
    initMap() {
      // init Leaflet map
      this.map = L.map(this.$refs.map)
      console.log(this.map)
      // init tile layer
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 16
      }).addTo(this.map)
      // geolocate user
      this.map.locate({ setView: true })
      // add marker
      let icon = L.divIcon({ 
        html: '<i class="fas fa-map-marker fa-2x text-warning"></i>',
        className: 'map-marker'
      })
      this.map.on('locationfound', async (e) =>{
        console.log(e)
        // set bounds
        // e.bounds._northEast
        // e.bounds._southWest
        this.latBounds.push(e.bounds._northEast.lat, e.bounds._southWest.lat)
        this.lngBounds.push(e.bounds._northEast.lng, e.bounds._southWest.lng)

        L.marker(e.latlng, { icon: icon }).addTo(this.map)
        await this.createMarkers()
      })

    async createMarkers() {
      let icon = L.divIcon({ 
        html: '<i class="fas fa-map-marker fa-2x text-danger"></i>',
        className: 'point-marker'
      })
      
      for( var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){
        let lat = Math.random() * (this.latBounds[1] - this.latBounds[0] + 1) + this.latBounds[0]
        let lng = Math.random() * (this.lngBounds[1] - this.lngBounds[0] + 1) + this.lngBounds[0]
        this.features.push({
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "name": "test point"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [lng, lat]
          }
        })
      }
      let geoJSON = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": this.features
      }

      await L.geoJSON(geoJSON, {
        pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
          return L.marker(latlng, { icon: icon })
        }
      }).addTo(this.map)
```

Thank you for the help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code for geolocation with position marker for Vue.js and leaflet.js. It's Vue.js mixin.
For radius, you can simply increase or decrease lat and lng.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

// Geolocation marker icon
const locationMarker = L.icon({
  iconUrl: require('@/assets/img/LocationMarker.svg'),
  iconSize: [30, 30],
  iconAnchor: [13, 30],
  popupAnchor: [0, -18],
});

export default {
  // Geo API for mobile
  // Find current device position
  beforeCreate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      return;
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.position = position.coords;
      if (this.center) {
        this.center.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
      }
    });
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * GeoLocation API
     */
    geoLoc() {
      // If geo exist
      if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
        // Give me position
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          // Get coords from position
          const lat = position.coords.latitude;
          const lng = position.coords.longitude;

          // Initialization Vue geoMarker
          const geoMarker = this.geoMarker;

          // Check if geomarker have the ID which I need
          if (geoMarker.hasOwnProperty(this.geoMarkerId)) {
            // If have than remove it
            this.map.removeLayer(geoMarker[this.geoMarkerId]);
          }
          // Than create new one with the same static ID
          let marker = L.marker(L.latLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)), {
            icon: locationMarker,
          });

          // Must be in new array !!
          this.geoMarker[this.geoMarkerId] = marker.addTo(this.map);
          // Update Leaflet Map with new center coords
          this.center = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);

          // Then remove it
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.map.removeLayer(marker);
          }, 7000);
        });
      } else {
        // Och noo someone have any Geolocation :(
        window.alert(this.$t('general.geoLocNotSupported'));
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Leaflet has it's own method t geolocate an user, why you've used navigator? can you explain what is exactly the `geoMarker` var and how it's assigned? I also see you have called two times the geolocation function, first time in `beforeCreate` and the second time into the `geoLoc` method, why this ?

Comment: `geoMarker` is only my Marker for the current position. I've tried several other ways but only this works fine in all browsers. If you find a better way you can share.

Comment: ok, so you have created it in `data()` and will assign a value with geolocation? How the position of the next marker near the user positiot will be created/assigned?

Comment: Here is a link to my project on GitHub - https://github.com/miko866/awesome-app
There you will find everything you need. It's a little older but it works. And sorry but at the moment I don't have much free time to create a new repo or sandbox.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the code, nice implementation. I'm using leaflet native library, but it's the same of vue-leaflet

Comment: Thanks, and yes you can use native leaflet but then you must write more code and do a hack for that. And vue-leaflet is the only wrapper with less code, it's pretty powerful and simple.